# mcrypt - number of possible encryption

Tags: php, encryption

I am using mcrypt function to encrypt some data - from php.net example.

I would like to know the number of encryptions for certain string. Let's say I would run the encryption for word "product" 1 milion times. Would I get 1 milion different encryptions ?

```
    function encrypt($s)
{
    # --- ENCRYPTION ---

    # the key should be random binary, use scrypt, bcrypt or PBKDF2 to
    # convert a string into a key
    # key is specified using hexadecimal
    $key = pack('H*', "bcb04b7e103a0cd8b54763051cef08bc55abe029fdebae5e1d417e2ffb2a00a3");

    # show key size use either 16, 24 or 32 byte keys for AES-128, 192
    # and 256 respectively
    $key_size =  strlen($key);

    # create a random IV to use with CBC encoding
    $iv_size = mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC);
    $iv = mcrypt_create_iv($iv_size, MCRYPT_RAND);

    # creates a cipher text compatible with AES (Rijndael block size = 128)
    # to keep the text confidential
    # only suitable for encoded input that never ends with value 00h
    # (because of default zero padding)
    $ciphertext = mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $key,
                                 $s, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv);

    # prepend the IV for it to be available for decryption
    $ciphertext = $iv . $ciphertext;

    # encode the resulting cipher text so it can be represented by a string
    $ciphertext_base64 = base64_encode($ciphertext);

    return $ciphertext_base64;

}
```

Comment: No, if you are using the same salt.

Comment: Whenever I refresh the page I get different string

Comment: We'll need to see the code. Block ciphers are deterministic - they will give the same output for the same input. But the key, IV or salt may differ per call.

Comment: Made an edit with my code

Answer (score 0):

If you pass the same parameters to `mcrypt_encrypt()`, you will get the same result. If you pass different parameters, such as a random IV, or a randomly salted password hash, then you will get different results. How are you constructing your call?